# How to make callout window appear when mouse hovers over this shape?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/helpme128/3kwwo53t/2/

```
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="shape" ng-draggable='dragOptions'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to make a callout window appear with the text `"Callout"` when the mouse pointer touches the white square. When the mouse leaves the white square, the callout window disappears. How can this be done? Are there angularjs modules suitable for this task?

Comment: What do you mean by a "callout window"?

Comment: Some conversation box. https://d37wxxhohlp07s.cloudfront.net/s3_images/823001/callout-handle_inline.png?1353938925

Comment: So a styled tooltip then?  Something [like this](http://720kb.github.io/angular-tooltips/)?

Comment: Yes. That will do fine. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the bootstrap popover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the fiddle I made, CSS only:
http://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/16/

```
.shape::after{
    display:none;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background-color:blue;
    content:'Callout';
    position:relative;
    left:20px;
}
.shape:hover::after{
    display:block;
}
```

EDIT:

Angular way: http://jsfiddle.net/3kwwo53t/18/

you can change text using the dragOptions

Comment: Upvoted. Is there some way not to use CSS? I don't know if AngularJS can be used to change contents of CSS.

Comment: you can't change the "callout" in this solution.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. This is why I would prefer the solution to use AngularJS so that the callout contents can be changed.

Comment: Hi, I added angular solution as well